# Create a slice from duplicate items of two slices

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have two slices:

```
slice1 := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
slice2 := []string{"c", "d", "e", "f"}
```

Expected result:

```
[]string{"c", "d"}
```

What's the best way to create a slice from duplicate items of `slice1` and `slice2` with this specifications:

1. Minimum code
2. Slices are large
3. Slices are not sorted
4. Do not modify the slices
5. They may not contain the duplicates

This is what I have tried:

```
slice1 := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
slice2 := []string{"c", "d", "e", "f"}
duplicateItems := []string{}
for _, item1 := range slice1 {
    for _, item2 := range slice2 {
        if item1 == item2 {
            duplicateItems = append(duplicateItems, item1)
        }
    }
}

fmt.Println(duplicateItems) // [c d]
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean the best way. I know how to use the loop.

Comment: **The best way** depends on many things, but mostly what is best for you? Fastest? Or something that uses the least memory? Or something that produces the least garbage (for gc)? Second, it depends on your input. Are slices small? Large? May they contain duplicates? Are they sorted? Are you allowed to modify the input slices? Should I add more questions?

Comment: @JaredChu SO is not a code generator. Write what you can come up with, and ask questions if you're stuck on something along the way. If you want to get your code reviewed, consider posting your code on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have updated my answer, please don't vote down so fast.

Comment: As @icza specified Best approach depends on the requirements you wants to fulfill.

Comment: `the minimum code` with me is the best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method sacrifices memory usage for big O complexity (speed).

```
// flatten the first slice into a map for O(1) constant time lookup
m1 := make(map[string]struct{})
for _, v := range slice1 {
    m1[v] = struct{}{}
}

var dup []string

// iterate slice 2, using the O(1) lookup.
for _, v := range slice2 {
    if _, exists := m1[v]; exists {
        dup = append(dup, v)
    }
}

// dup contains the duplicates
```

You only visit each of the elements once, but the memory requirements are much larger as slice1 needs to be stored in the map.

You could extend this code to flatten the smallest of the 2 slices into the map, for less memory requirements.

*it's worth noting that `map[string]struct{}` is used instead of `map[string]bool` because `struct{}` uses zero bytes of memory*

Comment: Thank you, it's showing an error: `type struct {} is not an expression` in line `mv[v] = struct{}`

Comment: `mv[v] = struct{}{}` should be `m1[v] = struct{}{}`. And it worked.

Comment: You're absolutely right @JaredChu, I've made the updates on the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will mark your answer as correct if there is no better answer till tomorrow.

Comment: @Zak: `struct{}` uses 0 bytes, but map buckets do not. Since the bucket size is fixed, and the bucket header and keys take most of the space, and buckets are at most 81.25% full, a `bool` bucket is only going to be a few percent larger at most. I prefer the readability of `if m1[v] {` over a theoretical few percent memory savings.

Comment: AFAICT this code returns wrong results for `slice1 = []string{"c"}` and `slice2 = []string{"c", "c"}` (though I'm unclear whether this violates requirement #5).

Comment: @hoffmale what would you expect the end results, duplicates slice, too look like?

Comment: I'd expect them to return `dup = []string{"c"}`. Currently, it returns `dup = []string{"c", "c"}`. However, I have trouble understanding requirement #5 (what is "they"?), so my understanding might be wrong if `slice1`/`slice2` on their own can only contain unique values.

Comment: @JimB, fair point. Readability is nice, I did my best to detail the options and explain why I'd chosen one over another. Readability arguments are always tricky ones.